# ida pro decompiling incorrect result

Tags: decompiler, ida

recently i tried to decompile in ida pro 6.1 the ida out puts incorrect result , for all i decompile the functions i only receive this code :

```
int result; // eax@1
return result;
```

for all functions i decompile instead of the correct decompile out put it only shows that, for example:

```
int __cdecl sub_975BB0()
{
    int result; // eax@1
    return result;
}
```

and some of them have null output :

```
void __cdecl sub_975C50(int a1)
{
  ;
}
```

the wondering thing it was working since 2 days ago but suddenly it is working like that.
i refreshed the ida 6.1 installation but no difference made . 
Thanks for helping ^^

Comment: How do you know that this is incorrect? E.g. can you debug the module and see more elaborate assembly code, and if so, are you sure you are disassembling (de-compiling) the exact same binary that you are debugging?

Comment: because the assemblies code is not matching with decompile code and it is not possible u always have that out put , btw i noticed it was working because at least in some functions i know what is the correct out put , and the out put in 2 other machines are the same and expected but mine is always have that out put i wrote above , and yes i am sure that i am decompiling the exact same binary also i am opening the idb i was using before and the same result with that happens

Comment: i think this can say what i mean : http://pastebin.com/z0dWrHkx

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Not sure why that happens, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have same problem, to solve it set your clock(date) to 2014, will work

Comment: License of IDA Pro Cracked version get expired, if you change clock, IDA understand license still valid